# AWS EKS aws-ebs-csi-driver 'allowautoiopspergbincrease' parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-ebs-csi-driver

I am using the `aws-ebs-csi-driver` add-on for Statefulsets. I would like to understand the difference between changing the parameter `iopsPerGB` to have the desired iops, with higher PVC capacity and using the `allowautoiopspergbincrease` parameter which will dynamically increase the `iopsPerGB` if I specify a lesser PVC capacity. I also would like to know which option is going to be higher on cost side.